# Get the number of cells with certain headertext in FooterRow (gridview)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to set some footer text in my gridview

I set my gridview so its row could moved freely based on user

what I'm looking for was something like this

```
Gridview1.FooterRow.Cells(DirectCast(FindControl(Gridview1.Columns(i).HeaderText), Integer)).Text="Test"
```

But VisualStudio will say that value of type bla bla bla cannot convert into Integer

I know it could be done If I'm looking for it with piece of code like

```
Dim CellNumber as Integer = 0
for i as Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count
    if GridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText="Key" Then
        CellNumber=i
    End If
Next

Gridview1.FooterRow.Cells(CellNumber).Text="Test"
```

I really want to know is it possible to do it in just one line like what I want??

Don't put too much attention in FindControl

It just me put random syntax inside of Cells

Thanks for any help/suggestion in advanced

Regards,

Siekh

Comment: Possible or not please tell me...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible to do that logic in one line, but the logic needs to satisfy the compiler.

For instance, the `FindControl` method is part of a control, it is not a top level method that can just be invoked. In your example, `FindControl()` should be invoked by the row object (`GridViewRow`).

Comment: yeah I know it impossible..what I'm trying to ask is it possible to do like that...just one line...don't give too much attention with the findcontrol

Comment: @JulianSanjaya - it is hard to say yes it is possible when the logic in your example fails. The short answer is yes, you can chain together calls and property values like you showed, as long as the compiler allows for it. That is not to say that it will work at run-time though.

Comment: hmm. I guess I will just use the long way one. Thanks for helping anyway

Comment: @JulianSanjaya - sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but feel free to up-vote the answer if you wish. :-)

Comment: nah nevermind. it's already good enough you still answering my question..thanks